# Angular Promise around callback

Tags: angularjs

I'm a bit confused by mixing promises and callbacks

I'm trying to do something like this in a factory

```
  startRecord: function (data) {
    return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
      myFunction(data,resolve,reject);
    })
  }
```

which calls

```
function myFunction(data,callback,error){
 ...do stuff
    if(worked)
       callback(response)
     else
       error(err)

 }
```

And then call it from within my controller like

```
 factory.startRecord(data).then(function(data)...).catch(function(error)...);
```

However the then or catch are never called..

Am I going the right way about this?

Comment: Looks ok at first glance. Can you create a JSFiddle / Plunker demo?

Comment: Seems to work as expected here ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/7lYGMJERPrySg6jj7gii?p=preview

Comment: It's more like this.. http://plnkr.co/edit/7ofUIBoDgy2LY9YDdZqX?p=preview which is also working.. but my code isn't working - must be something else going on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was the callback was being fired with an empty message before the full message was sent. I had to add some extra checks to stop the callback being fired until the message was ready.

Answer (score -1):

Angular **$http** call it self return promise, you just need to call it perfectly.

Sample code :

**Factory:**

```
angular.module(ApplicationName).factory('calendarFactory', ['$http', function ($http) {
   calendarFactory.testCall = function (request_params) {

        var req = {
            method: 'POST/GET',
            url: <URL>,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            data: request_params
        };

        return $http(req);
   }
}
```

**Controller :**

```
function testCall(start, end) {

  var request_paramas = {
     start: start.toString(),
     end: end.toString()
  };

  calendarFactory.testCall(request_paramas).then(
        function(success){
          //Success method
        },function(error){
          //Error method
  })
}
```

> Here I made a back-end http call from factory itself

Comment: I'm not using $http. I'm using $q. It's not doing a $http request.

Comment: try using http.. it will be easier

Comment: Thanks. The function that is being called isn't doing an http request, it's starting a camera recording via an API that uses TCP. I can't use http.